# Enterキーを押すと1列右へ移動させたい

Tags: emeditor

CSVセル選択モードでEnterキーを押すと、セルを1列右へ移動することはできますでしょうか。
（Excelではそれができます）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. EmEditor はベータ版を含めて最新版 (v21.2.905 以上) に更新してください。
2. [ヘルプ] メニューより [キーボード マップ] を選択します。
3. [検索] ボックスに [次のセル] とタイプします。

[image: EmEditor - キーボード マップ]

4. ↓ キーを押して、「次のセル (セル選択モードのみ)」を選択し、Enter を押します。
5. すべての設定のプロパティが表示され、「次のセル (セル選択モードのみ)」コマンドが選択されていることを確認します。

[image: EmEditor - すべての設定のプロパティ]

6. [追加するショートカット キー] テキスト ボックスをクリックしてから、Enter キーを押します。
7. 「Enter キーを割り当てますか?」というメッセージが表示されたら、OK をクリックします。
8. [割り当て] ボタンをクリックし、[OK] ボタンをクリックします。

以上で、CSV セル選択モードでファイルを開いていれば、Enter キーで右のセルに移動します。

Comment: 重宝いたします。